# Cipboard is copying the wrong text when click

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

When I click on the button to copy the first time I get blank 
and the second time I get the the last time I click on the button
and on the alert I also get alot of black space before the #emp_ext#.

Why is it reacting this way?

Im only would like it to work on IE9.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function ClipBoard(areatocopy) 
{
alert (holdtext.innerText);
holdtext.innerText = areatocopy.innerText;
Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}
</SCRIPT> 
<TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" STYLE="display:none;">
</TEXTAREA>

<cfif #Left(getAllDetails.emp_ext, 4)# eq '4643'>
    <div class="buttons">#emp_ext#
        <BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard(z#emp_ext#);"> <img src="copy-icon.png" alt=""/>  </BUTTON> 
            <pre id="z#emp_ext#" style=" display:none">
            #emp_ext#
            </pre>
    </div>
<cfelseif #Left(getAllDetails.emp_ext, 1)# eq '5'>

    <div class="buttons">655-emp_ext#
        <BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard(z#emp_ext#);"> <img src="copy-icon.png" alt=""/>  </BUTTON> 
            <pre id="z#emp_ext#" style=" display:none">
                #emp_ext#
            </pre>
    </div>
<cfelse #Left(getAllDetails.emp_ext, 1)# eq '6'>

    <div class="buttons">#emp_ext#
        <BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard(z#emp_ext#);"> <img src="copy-icon.png" alt=""/>  </BUTTON> 
            <pre id="z#emp_ext#" style=" display:none">
                #emp_ext#
            </pre>
    </div>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily display the textarea before calling `execCommand()`:

```js
function copyText(valueToCopy) 
{
    var holdtext = document.getElementById("holdtext");
    holdtext.innerText = valueToCopy;
    var range = holdtext.createTextRange();
    holdtext.style.display = "block";
    range.execCommand("Copy");
    holdtext.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="holdtext" style="display:none;"></textarea>

<div class="buttons">
    <button onclick="copyText('abc');">&#x29c9; abc</button> 
    <button onclick="copyText('123');">&#x29c9; 123</button> 
</div>
<div>
    Paste here to test if it worked:
</div>
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: now in the alert area alert (holdtext); , i get '[ojbect]

Comment: after making some changes i got mine to work , thanks